# Filtering for the value in A1

Tags: excel, formula, vba

I am trying to figure out a way to filter Column C for the value in A1, then put the formula in the first cell and copy down.  I have the below code but I can't seem to get it to work. I have an example of the spreadsheet below the code.

```
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A5").CurrentRegion
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=RC[1]"
            If .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
                With .Columns(2)
                .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1]&""-R21"""
                End With
            End If
    End With
```

[image]

Comment: What bit are you exactly having issues with? Try using the macro recorder to get an idea of what you should do for the autofilter

Answer (score 0):

Set range("A1") as a variable

```
Sub Button2_Click()
    Dim F As Range'declare F as a range
    Set F = Range("A1")'set F as range("A1")
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A5").CurrentRegion
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=F'Filter for F
        If .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
            With .Columns(2)
                .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1]&""-R21"""
            End With
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Here's another version, so you won't have to use Formulas.

```
Sub LoopThroughFilterd()
    Dim rws As Long, rng As Range, Fltr As Range, c As Range

    rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range("C6:C" & rws)
    Set Fltr = Range("A1")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

    With ActiveSheet.Range("A5").CurrentRegion

        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Fltr

        For Each c In rng.Cells

            If c.EntireRow.Hidden = 0 Then
                c.Offset(, -1) = c & "-R21"
            End If

        Next c
        .AutoFilter

    End With

End Sub
```

You can also Loop through the cells instead of filtering.

```
Sub LooPFor()
    Dim rws As Long, rng As Range, Fltr As Range, c As Range

    rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range("C6:C" & rws)
    Set Fltr = Range("A1")

    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If c = Fltr Then c.Offset(, -1) = c & "-R21"
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: I am rather new to the VBA world and was wondering if you could give a breakdown of what the sections within your code actually do, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your formula is only being added to the first cell in your filtered range. That is because a discontiguous SpecialCells range such as yours, i.e., C7, C10,C12:C15, etc., will consist of multiple [Areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213698%28v=office.11%29.aspx). If that's the case, you need to loop through the Areas with a For/Next:

```
Dim FilteredArea as Range

With ActiveSheet.Range("A5").CurrentRegion
    .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=RC[1]"
    If .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
        For Each FilteredArea in .Columns(2).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas
            FilteredArea.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1]&""-R21"""
        Next FilteredArea
    End If
End With
```

This is untested, but hopefully will give you an idea of how to work with Areas.

Comment: I am rather new to the VBA world and was wondering if you could give a breakdown of what the sections within your code actually do, if possible.